# Isekai manga about a hero that has been given a phoenix

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga I've been looking for is an isekai manga about the MC who has been isekai'd and has been given a phoenix as a pet/mount by a small goddess, approximately the size of a chicken.

Comment: This is incredibly terse, can you not remember anything else about the manga? When did you read it? Why was he given the phoenix? By whom? Can you remember any plot elements at all? What any of the characters look like? If you remember anything else please [edit] your question to include those details. At the moment this is highly likely to be closed as "Needs detail/clarity" as I imagine there are several mangas where something like this happens so it will only be random guesses to try and find it. Remember the more detail you add the more likely it is someone will find this for you.

Comment: The New Gate (TSUKI GA MICHIBIKU ISEKAI DOUCHUU)?

Comment: I think it was given to the MC by a goddess in the size of a chicken. @Valorum

Comment: @Solacia - If my answer below is correct, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It will reward me with some [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and helps with the administration of the site. Also, please consider [upvoting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer as well, if you haven't already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [Reborn as a Phoenix: A Normal Bird Can't Beat a Dragon, Right?](https://myanimelist.net/manga/131484/Fushichou_e_no_Tensei__Dragon_Taoseru_tte_Futsuu_no_Tori_ja_Nai_yo_ne)...?

[image]

The story begins with a boy hospitalised in modern day Japan, but soon shifts to a medieval setting where the same boy encounters a small flaming bird, which becomes his pet/companion.